# vue-simple-alert does not work in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-component

I am trying to add the [vue-simple-alert](https://github.com/constkhi/vue-simple-alert) package to my `Nuxt.js` application but its not working at all. I have followed below steps:

1. Install  and add the package to my `package.json` via command `npm install vue-simple-alert --save`.
2. Add a file `alert.js` under folder `plugins` within my nuxt.js project and add following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { VueSimpleAlert } from 'vue-simple-alert'

Vue.use(VueSimpleAlert)
```

3. Add the following lines within `nuxt.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/alert", mode:"client" }
  ],
```

Then within my `pages/text.vue` I added the alert message as per documentatioin:

```
this.$alert("Hello Vue Simple Alert.");
```

The message is displayed as a paragraph text on the Vue page rather than alert message.

[image]

I am not understanding whats wrong because I have used other packages similarly and everything worked well with them but same approach does not work for `vue-simple-alert`.

Comment: i dont get it, you talk about `vue-simple-alert` but use `'alertifyjs'`?

Comment: Some packages may not be compatible on the server, but here there are indeed 2 packages used at the same time. Please edit with the proper one please. Also, change `ssr: false` towards `mode: 'client'`, first one being obsolete. Please also check if you have any kind of error in your browser. A [repro] could be useful to debug it further too.

Comment: @bill.gates Really sorry since the `vue-simple-alert` was not working I was trying the `alertify`. Actually, I was asking for `vue-simple-alert` so I have changed the code please have a look and provide some suggestions.

Comment: Got it working with your package. Be careful because your package and the one in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73851665/8816585) are not really well maintained (2/3 years old without any commit already). So even if they work, may not be the best solution long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following configuration works fine.

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  ssr: true,
  target: 'static',
  plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/alert', mode: 'client' }],
}
```

`/plugins/alert.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { VueSimpleAlert } from 'vue-simple-alert' // importing like that here, because of the way the package is exported

Vue.use(VueSimpleAlert)
```

ESlint warning being

> Using exported name 'VueSimpleAlert' as identifier for default export.

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="nice">
    <button @click="alertMe">hey</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    alertMe() {
      this.$alert('Hello Vue Simple Alert.')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. My project is still not working as an alert message but rather displayed as text at the end of the page. I followed all your steps carefully (even directly copied to avoid any mistakes). Even removed the `alertify.js` to avoid any conflicts, still not working. Also, since this package is not well maintained can you please suggest a better `alert` package which is up to date?

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 then, the issue is coming from somewhere else and not related to that one. Please give us a [repro] to debug it further. Or check your console for some errors/DOM mismatch errors. I don't use such package myself mainly because it is usually baked-in into a CSS framework or I fallback to HeadlessUI (Vue3 only tho). Meanwhile, you can check [this list](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#notification) and check projects there, when you got a not so-old commit (6 months or so).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendation, I will pick the best suitable from the list :)